# Как можно разделить перехватываемые хуком функции

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Имеется приложение y.exe в котором описаны две простых функции(от usr32),

```
int msgbox1 = MessageBoxA(0,"msgbox 1","caption",MB_OK);
int msgbox2 = MessageBoxA(0,"msgbox 2","second caption",MB_OK);
```

Я через свое приложение x.exe - перехватываю MessageBoxA(из y.exe), используя метод trampoline, таким образом:

```
HookHelper::HookFunctionWithTrampoline(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(MsgBoxA), reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(MessageBoxA_Hook),trampoline);
```

---

доп. код

```
 typedef int(_stdcall*MsgBoxer)(HWND, char*, char*, UINT);
 MsgBoxer MsgBoxA = nullptr;
 int _stdcall MessageBoxA_Hook(HWND hwnd, char* text, char* caption, UINT type)
{
    return ((MsgBoxer)trampoline)(hwnd, "HOOKED!!!", caption, type);
}
```

Но действуя таким образом, хук перехватывает обе функции, и изменяет их.
Каким образом можно было бы их разделить(оставить выполнение первой без изменений, а вторую изменить), либо обратиться сразу к конкретной ?

Comment: reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(MsgBoxA) на (unsigned char*)MsgBoxA не заменяется? *_cast тут лишний, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Перехватывается не "функция" в y.exe, а MessageBoxA в соответствующей системной DLL. И ваши два вызова все равно приводят к одной API-функции.

Единственный способ отделять один вызов от другого в таком обработчике, как мне кажется - смотреть на адрес возврата. Но я думаю что можно обмануть и такую технику.

Comment: каким образом это можно осуществить(просмотр адреса ) ? И если уж обработчик не столь предрасположен к подобного рода задачам, нет ли описания - как его можно улучшить ?

Comment: Я не знаю чем и как вы хучите: гугление по "HookHelper::HookFunctionWithTrampoline" не дает ничего. Адрес возврата лежит на стеке как правило. "Улучшить" в данном случае это как? Ваш хук ловит ровно то, что вы указали - конкретную API функцию.

Comment: я этот метод можно сказать в гугле и нашел, поэтому еще не очень вникаю в то что он делает. Вы не могли бы привести пример получения адреса возврата ?

Comment: Не мог бы, потому что не пишу хуки, а вижу адреса возврата исключительно в отладчике. И я не знаю как и чем вы хучите. Берите OllyDbg и разбирайтесь с вызовами API.

Comment: в принципе у меня есть метод который работает конкретно с адресами, но он меня не устраивает ввиду того что - адрес в памяти нужно вычислять можно сказать в ручную(через дебагер)чтобы потом его вставить в хук. И я имел ввиду не то чтобы вы писали код, а скинули примерный образец(с решением) данной проблемы, но в другой реализации !

Comment: Не вижу проблемы: ваш код работает как вы и указали и перехватывает указанную функцию. Если вам нужно перехватить что-то другое - указывайте другой адрес. Возьмите IDA и посмотрите адреса, где нужно что-то хукать.

Comment: я бы хотел все-таки решить это используя метод -который не требует ручного поиска адреса! тут основная загвоздка в том как разделять то что я получаю ?

Comment: Адрес возврата - то что вам может помочь, лежит где-то на стеке. Смотрите в отладчике на входе в хук.

Comment: этот адрес можно получить без использования отладчика на прямую ? У меня и так частично подключен BeaEngine именно в HookFunctionWithTrampoline, если надо я могу скинуть этот код ? Просто в результате я хочу воздержаться от поиска адреса вручную !

Comment: Можно получить. Смотрите в отладчике как устроен стек на входе в хук. В хуке пишете получение адреса. Скорее всего через ассемблерную вставку придется делать.

Comment: очень был бы признателен вам если бы вы скинули мне пример - такой работы(в коде) !